# Inflate button from another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having issues to inflate a button from another layout.
Here is the first code with a ListView:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item_produto);

  btnAddNoCarrinho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Thats my another layout with a TableLayout with the button I need to inflate.

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAddNoCarrinho"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_addproduct">
        </ImageButton>
```

The error is: **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference**

Is there any way to inflate that layout? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image button should be part of your activity's view hierarchy. Android will only be able to find the views that are part of the `list_item_produto.xml` or included in it.

If your image button is in some other file you need to include it in your list_item_produto.xml. To include a layout you have to use [the include tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the button:

`ImageButton btnAddNoCarrinho = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNoCarrinho);`

So the whole code would be:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item_produto);

ImageButton btnAddNoCarrinho = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddNoCarrinho);

  btnAddNoCarrinho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Double check that your `btnAddNoCarrinho` button is in the layout file that you're inflating in `setContentView`**

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm still getting the same error :/